# If $\Sigma $ is the splitting field of $f$ over $K$ and $K \subseteq L \subseteq \Sigma$, show that $\Sigma$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $L$.

Tags: field-theory

This is question $9.7$ from *Stewart's Introduction to Galois Theory* (third ed.).

I said that $\Sigma $ being the splitting field of $f$ over $K$ implies that $\Sigma = K (a_1, a_2,..., a_n)$ and that $K \subseteq L \subseteq K (a_1, a_2,..., a_n)$ implies that $L = K (a_1, a_2,..., a_r)$ for some $r \le n$. Hence, as $f$ splits over $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma = L (a_{r+1}, a_{r+2},..., a_n)$, $\Sigma$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $L$.

Is this correct/complete ?

Comment: I think it is as it's pretty clear, almost obvious, that since $\;K\;$ contains all the roots of $\;f\;$ *and it is the smallest such one* then there is no smaller field containing *all* the roots. Now, I can't understand why you think $\;L\;$ has the form you wrote in your third line. We have that $\;\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt6)\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\,\sqrt3)\;$ , but the middle field isn't equal to neither of $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt2),\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)\;$ ...

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not correct - intermediate fields cannot be classified so easily. For example, the field $ \mathbf Q(\zeta_7) $ is the splitting field of $ X^7 - 1 $ over $ \mathbf Q $, but it has the subfield $ \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-7}) $ which is not generated over $ \mathbf Q $ by any combination of roots of $ X^7 - 1 $.

The correct approach is the following: $ \Sigma $ is the smallest field extension of $ K $ over which some polynomial $ P \in K[X] $ splits. Since $ K \subset L \subset \Sigma $ and $ P \in L[X] $, $ \Sigma $ is also the smallest extension of $ L $ over which $ P $ splits, so by definition it is the splitting field of $ P $ over $ L $.

Comment: I see now. Thank you.